# Adaptive Chained Payments: What are the necessary Credentials to Test in Sandbox?

Tags: paypal

We are confused on whether, or not you need special credentials to test Chained payments in Paypal's sandbox.  It seems that in order to make adaptive payments in a live environment you need special permission from Paypal, but does testing adaptive payments in the sandbox require these special permissions (credentials)? There is a application page on the developer site to create a new app that intends to use adaptive payments, but this app appears to be for the live environment, and does not mention testing. We wish to test adaptive payments in conjunction with our web application prior to obtaining live permissions. What are the steps to obtain the sandbox credentials to accomplish this, or can this be done with basic credentials?

Answer (score 0):

For sandbox, there is no need for additional permission. Just use the sandbox app ID - APP-80W284485P519543T. You can refer to the documentation below

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/